# Uploading picture after migration from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, migration, iis-6, iis-7.5

We've got a problem when trying to upload a picture to a IIS application after we've migrated from Windows Server 2003 & IIS 6.0 to Windows Server 2008 R2 & IIS 7.5 a couple of days ago.

You are allowed to choose a picture, but as soon as you click on the "Send"-button to perform the upload you're introduced to the following error message:

"

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/****/****/photouploadproc.asp, line 15

800401f3
```

"

In this code, the program uses a proprietary third library called w3upload.dll.
We tried to migrate the dll from the old IIS to the new one and give the access rights. 
It's still not working.

We're close to the edge of insanity, so please, if anybody has any hints or tips we've will gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd imagine your running in a 64bit application pool in IIS? you may need to set IIS to allow 32bit applications (dll's, com objects & assemblies etc).

[image: Nav to Admin Tools - IIS7 and load the properties of the application pool]

Also, have you registered the dll using regsvr32?

Comment: This solved my issue too in migrating from 2012 server to 2016 server (and installing ASP way after the fact). It was nothing particular either other than all dynamic asp code (i.e. it would display html, but no <%...%> code and) was blowing 500 errors with nothing in the event logs, etc. Many thanks, I never would have found that otherwise.