# classic ASP Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

Tags: iis, asp-classic, odbc, database-connection

I'm working on migrating an application from an IIS 6 to IIS 7.5 and am running into the weirdest issue:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' 

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified 

/Complaints/Login.asp, line 175
```

Here's the code around line 175:

```
  myConn = getDatabaseConnection()
  set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE lower(Login) = lower('" & uId & "') and Active = 1"
  rs.Open strSQL, myConn, 3, 3
```

Nothing special going on here...

here's the db method:

```
function getDatabaseConnection()

    Dim strConnection

        strConnection = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=server.domain.com;Database=cc;uid=acc;pwd=xxx;"

    Set GetDatabaseConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    GetDatabaseConnection.CommandTimeout = 60
    GetDatabaseConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 60
    GetDatabaseConnection.CursorLocation = 3

    GetDatabaseConnection.Open strConnection

end function
```

This seems to work in a similar classic asp application running in the same app pool (.NET 1.1)

I've tried: copy pasting the other app's code, using the connection string in place of the db method (throws 500 of course), changing app pools, google, & as another kick it works great on an IIS 6 server.

I took a look at [OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers Error "80004005'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280517/ole-db-provider-for-odbc-drivers-error-80004005) & my connection string seems correct & my ASP.NET 1.1 app pool can only run in 32-bit mode.  The DSNs set up on the previous server aren't relevant either.

I have the application working on IIS 5 on domain A and IIS 6 on domain A, but this 7.5 server is on domain B.  Thus I'm using the FQDN.  I haven't made any other domain specific changes though.  The system uses the above method to authenticate users.

Edit: also tried

```
strConnection = "dsn=my32bitdsn;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;"
```

I've inherited this code and am so so with classic ASP, can anybody help?

Updated code:

```
  Dim strConnection, oConn
  'get status 
  set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE lower(Login) = lower('" & uId & "') and Active = 1"
  'rs.Open strSQL, myConn, 3, 3

   strConnection = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=server.domain.com;Database=cc;uid=acc;pwd=xxx;"
  Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.CommandTimeout = 60
    oConn.ConnectionTimeout = 60
    oConn.CursorLocation = 3
    oConn.Open strConnection
  Set rs = oConn.Execute(strSQL)
```

Comment: Other things I've tried: setting up a 32 bit DSN and specifying that, enabling 32 bit mode in IIS via applicationpoolDefaults.  I got a driver incompatibility error on the dsn that i fixed by enabling 32 bit only to come back to the original error message :(

Comment: Yep, all the fields are eventually assigned.

Comment: I assure you that's not the issue.

Comment: comments should still be relevant to the question.

Comment: If I told you I'm getting an oil change, that would not be relevant to the question.

Comment: mind focusing on answering the question?  I'm not asking this question to debate SQL best practices on code I've inherited with you.

Comment: You're free to decline advice about SQL best practices; don't tell me that it's not relevant to your question.

Comment: Using named columns instead of * will not fix an ODBC driver issue.

Comment: Well obviously it won't. You need to perform a Pagan ritual for it to work. Hopefully someone will be able to *answer* your question below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be just cosmetic change, but might solve that issue as well:

```
Function getDatabaseConnection()
    Dim strConnection, oConn
    strConnection = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=server.domain.com;Database=cc;uid=acc;pwd=xxx;"

    Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.CommandTimeout = 60
    oConn.ConnectionTimeout = 60
    oConn.CursorLocation = 3
    oConn.Open strConnection

    Set getDatabaseConnection = oConn
End Function
```

I'm always afraid that using the function name directly will result in unneeded calls or weird results so got used to the above way.

Second thing is that you assign the connection as non object by not having "Set" which also might cause weird and unexpected problems. Change the line to:

```
Set myConn = getDatabaseConnection()
```

Hopefully one of the above will solve that weird problem.

Comment: that is better code, which I will replace it with anyways, but unfortunately it did not fix the problem.  I don't think it has to do with the code because the exact same code works on a different application, but if I can take a different approach I'm open to that too.

Comment: rs.Open strSQL, myConn, 3, 3

Comment: Weird, such error is usually thrown on the `.Open()` of the connection. In this case, try changing the line to: `Set rs = myConn.Execute(strSQL)` and see if this solve the problem.

Comment: it looks like moving the connection var into login & using the set method got asp to throw a 500 and the error's now viewable in the IIS log file: [Microsoft][ODBC_Driver_Manager]_Data_source_name_not_found_and_no_default_driver_specified .  Previous ones were too, just now it throws the 500.

Comment: I didn't notice but the 500 is coming off the logged in page, meaning I think it got through login.  I should be able to take it from here, thanks!

Comment: last, but not least it seems that moving the method's connection object into the main file did it, rs.Open strSQL, oConn, 3, 3 works now too.  Still, thanks.

Comment: Not 100% what exactly made it work, but glad I put you on the right path. :)

Comment: Thanks these settings work!! >> oConn.CommandTimeout = 60
    oConn.ConnectionTimeout = 60
    oConn.CursorLocation = 3

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have already solved this error, but if you would like to try and get it to throw a readable error you can try this as part of the connection string.

1. Your connection string says the db server is server.domain.com or did you just place that there to replace your companies information?
2. Give this a try:

   ```
   dim cn
   Set cn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   cn.ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=dbName;Data Source=(local) or computername;PWD=;Password=yourpassword;"
   on error resume next
   cn.Open
   if err.number <> 0 then response.Write(err.description) 
   on error goto 0
   ```