# Classic ASP: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

Tags: iis, odbc, iis-7.5, oledb

I am getting  this error:

*Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
functions.asp, line 258*

This is function.asp line 258:

```
Conn.Open Application("conn")
```

And in global.asa:

```
Application("conn") = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=DataSourceName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=DB_ID;Password=DB_PASS"
```

Things I already tried:

1. Enabling and disabling of 32-Bit Applications in Application Pool
2. Changed Managed Pipeline Mode to Classic (Tested Integrated also but to no avail)
3. ADd ODBC Client in ODBC Data Source Administrator both under SYSWOW64\odbcad32.exe and System32\odbcad32.exe

My site is Classic ASP, I am running Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit, my IIS is 7.5

Please let me know what you need from my end to further help me.

Been searching for almost 3 days, got the same suggestion as I already tried, still with no avail. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you checked this link?:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280517/ole-db-provider-for-odbc-drivers-error-80004005

Comment: yes I already checked that out, both ODBC.INI and ODBCINST.INI have ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server

Comment: i could not figure out this.check this link to may be you get some clue:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306345

Answer (score 0):

`Provider=sqloledb` is the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server, not the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers, which would be `Provider=msdasql`.

Try this ([from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) --

```
Application("conn") = "Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=dsnName;DATABASE=database;UID=MyUserID;PWD=MyPassword;"
```